# rollapply and xts does not work in the new version of xts

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo

If I run this simple code:

```
my_xts <- .xts(1:10*1,1:10)
rollapply(my_xts, list(seq(-2, 0)), sum, partial = 1)
```

In the new version of xts (0.9-3), I get:

```
Error in rollapply.xts(my_xts, list(seq(-2, 0)), sum, partial = 1) : 
(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'
In addition: Warning message:
In rollapply.xts(my_xts, list(seq(-2, 0)), sum, partial = 1) :
partial argument is not currently supported
```

While in the old xts (0.8-6) runs smoothly.

Seems it is related with the option width. As in the vignette of `rollapply`, "width can be a list regarded as offsets compared to the current time". In the new version this cannot be possible.

Any workaround?  Is there a possibility to call `rollapply` in a different way, in order to achieve the old behaviour?

Comment: Have you contacted the package maintainer?

Comment: not yet. I was going to ask for support here and then open a bug, if I don't get an answer here. Have you got any hint?

Comment: @Mitch76: I would appreciate if you could wait more than 5 minutes before posting a bug report... we do have other things to do than help users for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`rollapply.xts` wasn't registered as an S3 method until version 0.8-9.  That's why this worked for you previously.  Since there wasn't an xts S3 method, `rollapply.zoo` would have been dispatched, which would have returned a zoo object (not an xts object).

`rollapply.xts` currently does not support `width=list(...)`, but you can get the same results you did previously by converting your xts object to a zoo object before calling `rollapply`.

```
rollapply(as.zoo(my_xts), list(seq(-2, 0)), sum, partial = 1)
```

Comment: Do you have plan to reintroduce this feature of width in the rollapply.xts?

Comment: @Mitch76: As I said in my answer, the feature was never present in `rollapply.xts`, it was in `rollapply.zoo`. I plan on making `rollapply.xts` as consistent as possible with `rollapply.zoo`, which includes supporting this feature and the `partial` argument, but I cannot give you a timeframe when it will be completed.

Comment: Ok, in any case, thanks for the package xts, it's very useful!

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich Are you looking for contributors? Is this a patch needed in R code, or in C code?

Comment: @DarrenCook: contributions are always welcome. Look at xts/R/rollapply.xts.R.